# Formatting ng-style correctly for background-image shorthand

Tags: html, css, angular, sprite-sheet, ng-style

There's something not right with the below line. I have my height and width correctly showing up in my app. If I include `+ character.offsetX + 'px' + character.offsetY + 'px'` the background-image styling does not appear.

Character.offsetX and offsetY are hardcoded numbers supplied from the character object.

The examples I've found online are quite simple and don't show how to do the shorthand version of `background-image` for setting the `background-position`

```
<li *ngFor="let character of this.characterList" [ngStyle]= "{'height':'50px', 'width':'50px', 'background-image':'url(' + character.fullImagePath + ')' + character.offsetX + 'px' + character.offsetY + 'px' }"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-image` does not allow setting other `background-*` properties - you'll need to use the [`background`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background) shorthand for that instead:

```
<li *ngFor="let character of this.characterList" [ngStyle]= "{'height':'50px', 'width':'50px', 'background':'url(' + character.fullImagePath + ') ' + character.offsetX + 'px ' + character.offsetY + 'px' }"
```

Comment: Don't forget the space before each `character.offset...`.